# Monitor servers in ESXi environment

Tags: vmware-esxi, monitoring, nagios

I have my own environment on a ESXi host, so without access to the vCenter env. So I'm unable to setup nagios monitoring at first.

In my environment I have different kind of servers:
* Linux (Custom apps, Elastic Search, ...)
* Windows (Exchange, Domain Controller, SharePoint, Custom Apps, SQL Server ...)

Now I want to setup monitoring for all these (40) servers to check their available disk space, RAM, errors logged in the event viewer, in some logs (linux) and so on.

How and with which tool am I able to set this up? I have full control over this environment (but not on vCenter level).

It would be nice to get notified as soon as a process is running for > 90% more than a day, free disk space is <10%, ...

I already tried searching the ServerFault, but without success on something similary.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Install a monitoring suite of your choice *inside* of the virtual machines.

If you don't have the insight at the VMware vCenter level, this is going to be your best option.

Comment: Any suggestion of monitoring suites inside the VM's?

Comment: I'd like to understand why you don't have vCenter access.

Comment: Hi ewwhite, It's hosted by an external party, I just got my ESXI env assigned to me.

Comment: @BenCes Even remotly, easiy acces by vpn. myselft too I dont understand you don't have that access. Think to change of hoster.